# Graceful exception handling using DDD and Azure

Tags: c#, azure, exception, domain-driven-design

I am developing an MVC 5 web application using Domain Driven Design.  My controllers basically make calls to a service layer that either returns data(entities or lists of entities) or performs actions(business processes) depending upon the scenario.

Here is my confusion.  I need an effective strategy for logging exceptions that occur for troubleshooting purposes, while either displaying friendly messages to the user or not displaying at all under certain conditions.

For example, let's say some code in the service layer results in a NullReferenceException, I would like to handle this gracefully for the user while logging the exception for troubleshooting.  Additionally, let's say an exception occurs in the repository layer such as a connection error while trying to access the database.  This would be another scenario where I would like to handle in the same manner.

What is the recommended approach to this situation when you are dealing with DDD?  I have my repository -> service layer -> controller -> UI.

My current approach is to create an exception specific to the Repository Layer and one specific to the Service Layer and failures that occur in the Repository Layer would be bubbled up to the Service Layer where the UI could handle according to its discretion.

However, I would like to utilize Azure logging to add the errors to log files for further investigation.

1. What is the recommended way of handling errors between the various layers?
2. What is the recommended place for adding logging in this layered scenario?

It seems like it would be bad to put azure logging in the service or repository layers, at least without using a wrapper class?

Is there a global way to handle this without having to account for every exception(a catch all for any exceptions that might fall through the cracks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not really a definitive answer here, but the following is a solution that I have used a few times and it works quite well. (Not only for exception handling, but for all cross cutting concerns).

A possible way is to use the decorator pattern. I have written a post about this which you can check here: http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/06/02/simplify-code-by-using-composition/

I also recommend you check out Greg Young's video on roughly the same subject: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring

In order to use the decorator pattern, you could transform your methods that return data and execute business processes into Query and Command handlers. Say you have the following methods:

```
List<Customer> GetCustomers(string country, string orderBy)
{
    ...
}

void CreateInvoice(int customerId, decimal amount)
{
    ...
}

void CreateCustomer(string name, string address)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, these methods do not conform to an interface, so you can't extract one. However, you could change them to a query and command pattern:

Interfaces:
    interface IQueryHandler
    {
        TResult Handle(TQuery query);
    }

```
interface ICommandHandler<T>
{
    Handle(T command);
}
```

Now you can change your classes so they implement this interface:

```
class GetCustomersHandler : IQueryHandler<CustomerQuery, List<Customer>>
{
    List<Customer> Handle(CustomerQuery query)
    {
        // CustomerQuery is a simple message type class which contains country and orderby
        // just as in the original method, but now packed up in a 'message'
    }
}

class CreateInvoiceHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateInvoice>
{
    public void Handle(CreateInvoice command)
    {
        // CreateInvoice is a simple message type class which contains customerId and amount
        // just as in the original method, but now packed up in a 'message'
    }
}
```

When you have this, you can create a logger-class that implements the logging but wraps (decorates) the underlying class:

```
class QueryExceptionHandler<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
{
    IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _innerQueryHandler;
    public QueryLogHandler(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> innerQueryHandler)
    {
        _innerQueryHandler = innerQueryHandler;
    }

    TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
         try
         {
             var result = _innerQueryHandler.Handle(query);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
              // Deal with exception here
         }
    }
}
```

When you want to use this you could instantiate it like this (from the UI code).

```
IQueryHandler<CustomerQuery, List<Customer>> handler = 
    new QueryExceptionHandler<CustomerQuery, List<Customer>>(new GetCustomersHandler());

var customers = handler.Handle(new CustomerQuery {Country = "us", OrderBy = "Name"});
```

Of course, this queryExceptionHandler can be reused for other handlers as well (example):

```
IQueryHandler<InvoiceQuery, List<Invoice>> handler = 
    new QueryExceptionHandler<InvoiceQuery, List<Invoice>>(new GetCInvoicesHandler());

var invoices= handler.Handle(new InvoiceQuery {MinAmount= 100});
```

Now the exception handling is done in one class and all of your other classes don't need to be bother with it. The same idea can be applied to the business actions (command-side).

Aside from that, in this case I just added one layer for exception handling. You could wrap the exception handler inside a logger as well and so build various decorators on top of each other. That way you can create one class for logging, one for exception handling, one for ...

Not only does it allow you to separate that behavior from the actual classes, but it allows you to customize it for every different handler should you wish so (wrap a customer handler with exception and logging and a invoice handler only in a logging handler for example)

Constructing your handlers like in the example above is very cumbersome (especially when you start adding multiple decorators), but it's just to show you how they work together.

It would be a better idea to use dependency injection for that. You could do manual DI, a functional approach (see Greg Young's video) or use a DI-container.

I know it looks like a very complicated sample, but you'll soon notice that once you have the little structure set up, it's actually quite easy to work with. You can refer to my article where you can also see a solution using a DI-container.

Comment: I am not sure I like the idea of calling an exception handler every time I want to use a command or query handler.  Would it be better to call it something else? +1.

Comment: You don't need to call an ExceptionHandler. From the point of view of the consumer, it will just be an `IQueryHandler<CustomerQuery, List<Customer>>` . The specific instance will be an exceptionhandler, wrapped around a `GetCustomersHandler`. You usually deal with this in a composition root, or a DI-container if you're using one